# commands history

Tags: bash, nfs, history

So, I wanted to see all the history of commands of a certain  user, me more specifically, the probem is that I want to do soo in a NFS server that I am connected through ssh, so, everytime I disconect from it the history restart's.

Any help will be welcome.

Comment: `cat ~/.$(SHELL)_history` please try to do some research next time

Comment: @j-money Post as an answer, please

Comment: I tried, but the coomands didn't work on my server, i will try yours and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can find the history for your specific user under `~/.$(SHELL)_history` as `~` expands to your users home directory `/home/USER/`